# BASH binary to Hex to match PHP bin2hex function?

Tags: conversion, binary, hex

In bash I can call PHP and run the following:

```
testKey='8798(*&98}9%"^8&]8_98{9798**76876'
testHex=$(php -r "echo bin2hex('$testKey');")
echo $testHex
```

And that will result in 
`38373938282a2639387d3925225e38265d385f39387b393739382a2a3736383736`

I've got a system where PHP isn't available, is there anyway to get the same result using just bash ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have `hexdump` lying around:

```
$ printf "%s" "$testKey" | hexdump -ve '/1 "%x"'
38373938282a2639387d3925225e38265d385f39387b393739382a2a3736383736
```

`-e` sets a format string for `hexdump`, which 'must be surrounded by double quote ( " ) marks'. `/1` uses one byte at a time for the format string `%x`, which prints it in hex (otherwise the byte order could result in different output). `-v` is to make it print repeated data as well (the default is to replace them with a `*`).

Comment: Thanks this works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, with `xxd` you can do exactly the same:

```
testKey='8798(*&98}9%"^8&]8_98{9798**76876'
testHex=$(echo -n "${testKey}" | xxd -p -c 100)
```

The -p flag is for a hex dump without offset information.
The -c 100 flag is for a line-length of 100 characters(default is 16, max 256).

Comment: Why does your output contain the `0a` in the end?

Comment: ah, thats the newline added by <<< i will fix this

Answer (score 0):

With "just bash", using a trick from [BASH print question (printf \$(printf '%03o' $1))](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/557039/65304)

```
$ for ((i=0;i<${#testKey};i++)); do printf '%x' "$(printf "'%c" "${testKey:i:1}")"; done; echo
38373938282a2639387d3925225e38265d385f39387b393739382a2a3736383736
```

With perl's `unpack`

```
$ perl -E 'say unpack "H*", $ARGV[0]' "$testKey"
38373938282a2639387d3925225e38265d385f39387b393739382a2a3736383736
```